# pdfsharp - font embed?

Tags: pdfsharp

I am given a file that has some other language font.  They can not download the font, so they want me to embed it in the pdf.

Now, I only have PDF Reader, so I cant edit or create a pdf file. so I decided to quickly do it in C#.NET using PDFSharp library, but I just cant seem to figure out how to embed fonts using pdfSharp?!

Also, it's only 1 file that I have to process, so if you know of a way to do it manually, then that would be great too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. For each font you want to embed like this:

```cs
var options = new XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
var font = new XFont("Times New Roman", 12, XFontStyle.Regular, options);
```

Then if you use the font, it will get embedded.

If you want all fonts use on  a page to be embedded you can do it like this:

```cs
var page = new PdfPage();
var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
gfx.MFEH = PdfFontEmbedding.Automatic;
```

The second approach will also work for any fonts used in MigraDoc code.

Comment: Does this mean the fonts need to be installed in the server? Is there a way to point to a font file in the FS?

Comment: @JamesReategui Check out the following sample, as it is about "private fonts": http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PrivateFonts-sample.ashx

Comment: What is `this` in that example?