# Formatting text using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I want to apply style to

string "Helloword"

and have style properties

like fontFamily='Verdana',  fontStyle='bold', FontSize='12', textDecoration='underline', textAlign='center', fontColor='#FF0000', x=100 and y=100.

I want to display this string in PDF using PDFsharp. can anyone suggest me how to do that?

I'm using `XFont` and `XGraphics.DrawString` method but I'm not able to apply all above styles.

Comment: may be this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557164/pdfsharp-font-embed/1565122#1565122

Comment: I want to apply all style properties metioned above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string is slightly incorrect, but I hope all other requirements are met:

```
// Create a font
XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 12, XFontStyle.Bold | XFontStyle.Underline);

// Draw the text
gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)),
  100, 100,
  XStringFormats.Center);
```