# Formatting text using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

[Refere this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17759711/842112)

For some reasons I moved from PDFSharp to ItextSharp dll. I wanted to achive the above from Itextsharp. can u help me plz.

Comment: what is  x=100 and y=100.please describe.

Comment: x and y positions of string in the pdf.

Comment: Please outline your entire question rather than linking to other resources.

Answer (score 3):

Use This function

```
 private void CreatePdf()
 {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 20, 10);
        doc.Open();
        int totalfonts = FontFactory.RegisterDirectory("C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (string fontname in FontFactory.RegisteredFonts)
        {
            sb.Append(fontname + "\n");
        }

        doc.Add(new Paragraph("All Fonts:\n" + sb.ToString()));
        Font arial = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, BaseColor.GRAY);
        Font verdana = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 20, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE, new BaseColor(255, 0, 0));

        //rdana.SetStyle(4);
        iTextSharp.text.Font baseFontNormal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(verdana);
        using (FileStream msReport = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            doc.Open();

            PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, msReport);
            PdfPCell cell;
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("User I", new Font(verdana)));

            cell.Colspan = 4;

            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            cell.VerticalAlignment = 1;
            cell.Border = 0;
            table.AddCell(cell);

            table.AddCell(cell);
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(table);
            doc.Close();
        }
  }
```

I don't have position idea.

Comment: Regarding positioning: don't do `doc.Add(table)`, use the `WriteSelectedRows()` method. Another suggestion: why don't you use `ColumnText` to position content?

Comment: thnx! for suggestion.and where am i using *ColumnText?*

Comment: You should use `ColumnText` instead of `PdfPTable`. Read the documentation (iText in Action) or take a look at the examples of chapter 3.